# Reverse video cursor in Emacs

Tags: emacs

How do I make the cursor in Emacs a black box with underneath text displayed in white?

like so:
[image: reverse cursor]

Screenshot is from the Carbon Emacs package, but I want the same behavior in Cocoa Emacs 23.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least in my version of Emacs, that **is** the default cursor.  You can use `M-x customize-face RET cursor RET` to change it, if you want.  If you want to stop the cursor from blinking, you can use `M-x customize-variable RET blink-cursor-mode RET`.

**Update:** Since you updated your post to mention the version of Emacs you're using, I could confirm that this is a bug in Cocoa Emacs 23 for Mac OS X.  I see what you mean - nothing seems to invert the character underneath.

There's a patch to fix it (partially) [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/emacs-app-dev-@lists.sourceforge.net/msg00783.html).

This and other issues ensure I'm still using Carbon Emacs.

Comment: Using this I can get a solid black box as a cursor, but I can't find a way to get the white text.

Comment: This is a bug in Cocoa Emacs (see my revised answer).

Comment: Unfortunate, was hoping it would be fixable in elisp. Thanks