# Changing Emacs cursor color/interaction with color themes

Tags: emacs, colors, cursor

Because of [this bug in Cocoa Emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337363/reverse-video-cursor-in-emacs) using the box cursor obscure the character beneath the cursor, and using the bar cursor with solarized has tended to make me not be able to tell where it is in a sea of text. So I want to have the cursor be a *red* bar. I thought this would work, in my .emacs:

```
(when window-system
  (require 'color-theme-solarized)
  (global-set-key (kbd "C-c l") 'color-theme-solarized))
(case window-system
  ('ns (progn
        (defadvice color-theme-solarized (after cursor-more-visible)
          "change the cursor color so it stands out more"
          (set-cursor-color "red"))
        (ad-activate 'color-theme-solarized)
        (color-theme-solarized 'dark)
        [...]
        ))
  [...])
```

But the programmatic invocation of `color-theme-solarized` actually does not change the cursor color. The cursor color *does* change if I invoke `color-theme-solarized` interactively (or in the *scratch* buffer with `C-xC-e`)—so the advice is being taken, sort of.

Adding a `(setq default-frame-alist '((cursor-color . "red")))` (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4642835/how-to-change-the-cursor-color-on-emacs)) doesn't seem to help. Just for kicks I tried changing `(color-theme-solarized 'dark)` to `(call-interactively color-theme-solarized)`, with no success.

How can I get the cursor color to be automatically set to red at startup?

Answer (score 4):

The default-frame-alist values are used for NEW frames that are created. They don't affect the current frame. You can set [initial-frame-alist](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/elisp-manual-21/elisp_450.html) if you want to specify the initial frame's values in your .emacs file. To change just the cursor color in the current frame, use:

```
(set-cursor-color "red")
```

Comment: I tried that, doesn't work. Even if `(set-cursor-color "red")` comes after `(color-theme-solarized 'dark)`, the cursor color on startup is not red. Calling `(trace-function 'set-cursor-color)` reveals that when the advised `color-theme-solarized` is run, it is in fact calling `set-cursor-color`---but it doesn't take effect when emacs starts up.

Comment: ... but with further investigation `(add-hook 'window-setup-hook '(lambda () (set-cursor-color "red")))` and `(add-hook 'after-make-frame-functions '(lambda (f) (with-selected-frame f (set-cursor-color "red"))))` together do what I want.

Comment: Thanks - that was the only way I could get it working also. rediculous  how complicated that was.